# Finding the number of words without split() or heavy regex

Tags: javascript, string

Ive been struggling with this a bit and haven't found anything good on the website. I'm trying to find the number of words in a textarea without split() (cuz it counts whitespaces and miscounts words in some situations) this is what i've tried :

```
text.addEventListener('input', () => {
    let wordCounter = 0;
    let sentenceCounter = 0;
    let charCounter = text.value.split('').length;
    let flag = false;
    let flag2 = false;

    if(text.value === ' ' || text.value === ''){
        wordCounter = 0;
    }

    for(let z = 0; z < text.value.length; ++z){
        if(text.value[z] == '.' && flag == false){
            sentenceCounter++;
            flag = true;
        }

        if((/\w/).test(text.value[z])){
            flag = false;
        }
    }

    for(let z = 0; z < text.value.length; ++z){
        if(text.value[z] == " " && flag2 == false){
            wordCounter++;
            flag2 = true;
        }

        if((/\w/.test(text.value[z]))){
            flag2 = false;
        }
    }

    sentences.innerHTML = `${sentenceCounter} : Sentences`
    char.innerHTML = `${charCounter} : Characters`
    words.innerHTML = `${wordCounter} : Words`
});
```

the problem here is that it counts words only if press space so that means "fa" is not counted as a word but "fa " is. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Given that regexes are usually turned into state machines that are compiled to bytecode by most browsers, they are probably far more lightweight (= faster) then your loop that iterates over every char. So "heavy regex" is kinda ...

Comment: Hmm didn't know that...I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increase the counter when you find a letter, instead of when you find a space. You can also count words and sentences on the same loop. To finish a word, had to change from comparing to `" "` to `\W`.

```js
let sentenceCounter = 0, sentenceFinished = false,
  wordCounter = 0, wordFinished = true,
  input = "Test text. Test.";
for (let z = 0; z < input.length; ++z) {
  var letter = input[z];
  if (!sentenceFinished && letter == ".") {
    sentenceCounter++;
    sentenceFinished = true;
  }

  if (sentenceFinished && /\w/.test(letter)) {
    sentenceFinished = false;
  }

  if (!wordFinished && /\W/.test(letter)) {
    wordFinished = true;
  }

  if (wordFinished && /\w/.test(letter)) {
    wordCounter++;
    wordFinished = false;
  }
}
console.log(`Words: ${wordCounter}, Sentences: ${sentenceCounter}`);
```